# Strange error when updating an application to Vue2

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-elixir

After running vue-migration-helper and change all i need to update i'm getting this error bellow.

```
vue2.default.user is not a function
```

Console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _vue2.default.use is not a function
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:1624), <anonymous>:153:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:1624)
    at __webpack_require__ (vendor.js:53)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (vendor.js:24)
    at app.js:1
```

Anyone aware of what triggered this error?

______ UPDATE
       Ok, looks like the error is about the new Vue() not a function, maybe something with Laravel-Elixir-Webpack.

[image: console error]

Comment: It's pretty hard to be aware of what caused the problem when you don't have a stacktrace or a single line of code.

Comment: @David L fair enough. Added the error to my question. But the error don't say nothing for me actually, i'm try removing each dependence now.

Comment: Seems to be VueStrap, it's not compatible with Vue 2.0. Not sure yet.

Comment: What vue plugins are you using?

Comment: @Deepak sadly a lot of plugins, look this gist [link](https://gist.github.com/marceloch2/1e29de6589d20855cbd91f299cea4623)

But now i have a different error and i'll update the question. Thanks for you efforts Deepak

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for future mates facing the same problem. To solve the problem i've changed from Laravel Elixir to the new Laravel Mix.

Also you need to add vue-template-compiler to your package.json and this package need have the same version as your Vue, this is mandatory.

So for now i have Vue 2.3.0 and vue-template-compiler 2.3.0.

If doubts with webpack.config.js here is the Gist with what i have now [link](https://gist.github.com/marceloch2/1af211541736d9204dea23d2d0ebe739)